# Autocomplete Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

Need to implement a filter autocomplete and I don't know how. Please help!
I've already seen some examples but I cannot use them
Here the code:

```
 <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                  <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                  <input  
                  matInput placeholder="name" 
                  name="name" type="text" 
                    [formControl] = "myControl
                   [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
                   <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                    <mat-option></mat-option>
                    <mat-option #matOptionEvent *ngFor="let user of 
                    responseuser?.names"
                    [value]="user.id" [title]="user.id">
                    {{ user.id }}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
                </mat-form-field>
```

TS

```
export class AutocompleteOverviewExample {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  responseUser: Observable<State[]>;

  users: User[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.responseUser= this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(user=> user? this._filterUser(user) : this.users.slice())
      );
  }

  private _filterUser(value: string): users[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.users.filter(state => state.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

API response into the ngOnInit

```
this.service.getUser().then(
      (value: any) => {
        this.responseUser = value;
      });
```

---

In the end the model:

```
export interface UserList{
   user: User[];
}
export interface User{
    UserCode?: string;
    activity?: string;
    name?: string;
}
```

---

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pzc1r?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.ts

Just pass your api result to the options array. If you have a certain type then change the options string[] array to options your_interface[].

One more thing I would recommend not calling the API endpoint after every keystroke but however pipe sometime between events and fire call if the change is detected

```
.pipe(
      debounceTime(150), 
      distinctUntilChanged()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[stackblitz autocomplete example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-angular-autocomplete)

try to use this example hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use primeNg's autocomplete simple example given below:

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="text" [suggestions]="results" (completeMethod)="search($event)"></p-autoComplete>
```